# Python: Read binary file into buffer as integer then Slice

Tags: python, binary, integer, slice

In python, how do i load a binary file into a buffer then read individual bytes as numbers not strings.?

Comment: I realize my initial question wasn't all that clear and im still missing something.  I understand how to print an entire file as shown with HennyH's example below but what if I only want to print byte 5?  or I want to print all bytes from 663 to 765?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('binary.txt',"rb",buffering=-1) as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            print(c)
```

With a file like:

```
"abcde"
```

Produces

```
>>> 
97
98
99
100
101
```

The optional buffering argument is described here:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1
>   to indicate the size of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no buffering
>   argument is given, the default buffering policy works as follows:
>
> •Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the
>   buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying
>   device’s “block size” and falling back on DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On many
>   systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.

[Python io.open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open)

And if you were really keen and planned on manipulating them, you can convert each line into a [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray)

```
line = bytearray(line)
```

To answer your comment this demonstrates how to filter out which characters you iterate over:

```
with open('binary.txt',"rb",buffering=-1) as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in [b for b in line if b in range(663,765)]: #in a certain range
            print(c)
        for c in [b for b in line if b == 5]: #is a certain number
            print(c)
```